# Filtering/Searching in one column with MAC

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatable, filtering

I have MAC address in one column, eg. aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff. How can I find current mac address via search box with more transcription support? I want to support also aabbccddeeff and aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff for the same record (aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff).
Thank you.

Comment: I do not want add next hidden columns with other formats.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve